# Is it good to use ItemPage (schema.org) to my courses?

Tags: html, schema.org

I'm describing a site for distance education with schema.org and JSON. Any pages are with this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
```

but I have many pages for every course - German course, Economics course, Hairdressing course etc. (Product pages) and I was described them with

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">
```

How is better to describe them - with WebPage or with ItemPage ?
In schema.org the description for ItemPage is "A page devoted to a single item, such as a particular product or hotel." I am not sure what is better. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is about a single course, then yes, you may use [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage).

As a general rule, always [go with the most specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29749371/1591669). So if you have a [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage), check its "More specific Types"; if one of the types applies to your case, select it; otherwise, keep `WebPage`.

Of course this type only represents the *web page* about your course, not the course itself. So you’d probably want to use [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) to reference an [`EducationEvent`](http://schema.org/EducationEvent) (or whichever type applies).

Comment: Thanks! And how can I describe category course pages? "Language courses", "Professional courses"? This question is not for "WebPage" only. If "German course" is "Product", what is the list "Language courses?"

And - the button for contact is with CommunicateAction, isn't it?

Comment: @Petko: You mean a webpage that lists several courses? The type [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) comes to mind (unless the list is a result of a search, in which case [`SearchResultsPage`](http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage) applies). Both types are linked from `WebPage` in the "More specific Types" section, as explained in my answer.

Comment: @Petko: (The second question re. the contact button seems to be a separate topic, which would require its own question.)