# Breadcrumb with non-linked level

Tags: schema.org, breadcrumbs, json-ld

I try to implement a JSON-LD breadcrumb for a web site with the following structure:

```
Home
  Topic A (No content)
    Article A1
    Article A2
  Topic B (No content)
    Article B1
    Article B2
  Topic C (No content)
    Article C1
    Article C2
```

My problem is that all pages on level 2 (Topic A/B/C) are empty pages that can not be reached by the main navigation. People should not navigate to "Topic A" etc.

How can I express this behavior in my JSON-LD breadcrumb?

This is what my JSON-LD looks like for page "Article A1":

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "name": "Home",
    "item": "https://example.com/"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "name": "Topic A",
    "item": ""
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 3,
    "name": "Article A1",
    "item": "https://example.com/topic-a/article-a1"
  }]
}
```

When I try to validate the above code with https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool it always complains:

```
itemListElement     
  @type     ListItem
  position  2
  name      Topic A
  item      Field item requires a value.
```

Specifying anything else than a URL will result in:

> Value for field item must be a valid URL.

How can I describe that 2nd level pages are not reachable by a URL using JSON-LD?

Comment: Why include these in the first place? Whom do you expect to make use of it, and why should they?

Comment: As far as I understand the semantics of JSON LD those page path elements are still valuable information about structure of my content. Leaving those out would imply that e.g. "Article A1" is a child node of "Home". If you have any documentation explaining why those information should be left out I am quite thankful for any reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of breadcrumbs is to see the current page in the hierarchy, and to navigate to its parent pages. Page-less entries shouldn’t appear there, because they can’t be navigated to.

Schema.org’s [`BreadcrumbList`](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList) type is only meant for web pages (but such a page-less topic isn’t a web page, of course):

> A BreadcrumbList is an ItemList consisting of a chain of linked **Web pages**, typically described using at least their URL and their name, and typically ending with the current page.

This is also what Google requires for their [Breadcrumbs rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb?hl=en) (in case you want to get this feature):

> A user can navigate **all the way up** in the site hierarchy, **one level at a time**, by starting from the last breadcrumb in the breadcrumb trail.

So, you could either omit the page-less topics in the `BreadcrumbList`, or make them actual pages.

If you don’t want them to exist as pages, you could still convey what the topic is (see example with `about` below), but I wouldn’t expect this data to get used by consumers that are interested in your breadcrumbs:

```json
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
 "itemListElement":
 [
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
   "position": 1,
   "item":
   {
    "@id": "https://example.com/",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "name": "Home"
   }
  },
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
   "position": 2,
   "item":
   {
    "@id": "https://example.com/article-a1",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "name": "Article A1",
    "about": {
     "@type": "Thing",
     "name": "Topic A"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

HTML+RDFa:

```html
    <ol typeof="schema:BreadcrumbList">

      <li property="schema:itemListElement" typeof="schema:ListItem">
        <a property="schema:item" typeof="schema:WebPage" href="https://example.com/">
          <span property="schema:name">Home</span>
        </a>
        <meta property="schema:position" content="1" />
      </li>

      <li property="schema:itemListElement" typeof="schema:ListItem">
        <a property="schema:item" typeof="schema:WebPage" href="https://example.com/article-a1">
          <span property="schema:name">Article A1</span>
          <span property="schema:about" typeof="schema:Thing">
            <meta property="schema:name" content="Topic A" />
          </span>
        </a>
        <meta property="schema:position" content="2" />
      </li>

    </ol>
```

Comment: `item` is defined as `Thing` [here](https://schema.org/ListItem), is it fine to make it of type `WebPage` (or `CollectionPage`/...)?

Comment: @Ethan: This means that the `item` property expects a value of type `Thing`. As `WebPage` is [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29749371/1591669) a `Thing` (`Thing` > `CreativeWork` > `WebPage`), `WebPage` is an expected value for `item`. See